# PXE with DHCP on another server

Tags: dhcp, pxe-boot

Hi I have the following setup :

- A router that does DHCP
- a PXE server (VMware workstation Bridged mode)
- a client I want to boot on (VMware workstation Bridged mode)

I was following this guide [on setting up a PXE boot infrastructure](http://andys.org.uk/bits/2010/03/22/pxe-booting-a-debian-squeeze-install/) but I'm stuck now, since I cannot install DHCP on the PXE server (won't it conflict with my DHCP on my router?) and apperently I need to specify a file it needs to fetch to do a PXE boot.

How can I achieve a working PXE server without the DHCP server being the PXE server itself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is absolutely zero requirement for the DHCP server to be the same machine as the TFTP server (there's no such thing as a "PXE server").  You simply configure the DHCP server to provide the necessary DHCP options for PXE booting.  Good luck managing *that* on a dinky toy consumer router, though.

Comment: basically there is no way that I can do this on my dinky router then ?

Comment: I'd say it's incredibly unlikely.  I've never seen a consumer CPE with that complete a feature set.

Comment: might there be a way to statically point to a PXE server and the file ?

Comment: No, the DHCP server just flat out will not support it.  I'd just turf the dinky toy as your DHCP server and use a real one off the TFTP server -- or chuck your entire PXE infrastructure on a separate physical segment, and still run the PXE over this separate LAN.  It works quite well, and VLANs are cheap (*especially* in virtual gear).

Comment: got it all up and working now :D only the boot.txt isnt displayed but everything else works fine

Answer (score 2):

```
subnet 192.168.51.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
       range 192.168.51.64 192.168.51.80;
       filename "pxelinux.0";
       next-server 192.168.51.1;
       option routers 192.168.51.1;
}
```

It looks like the requirement of the extended DHCP "filename" option rules out most router-based DHCP servers. The typical router-based DHCP server is mainly focused around the minimal functionality of just managing IP addressing.

Answer (score 0):

Recently figured out how to do this with a dinky consumer router running DD-WRT.

Go to DNSMasq settings in Services. Make sure DNSMasq is enabled. Then add this line to the box marked "Addition DNSMasq Options":

```
dhcp-boot=pxelinux.0,,192.168.5.143
```

Where "192.168.5.143" is the PXE (TFTP) server's address. And "pxelinux.0" is the file to boot.

Answer (score 0):

There is proxydhcp servers (dnsmasq can be configured to do this) which only provides the missing options from the normal DHCP server.

- external DHCP
- TFTP server with you NBP
- ProxyDHCP that adds the extra options.

All of these can be on different machines/devices